# Rev. 17:14b - In the context, are "those with him," called (by God, inviter) , and chosen and faithful (invitees), or called and chosen, and faithful?

Tags: revelation, grammar

Text:Rev. 17:14b (ESV):

"...and those with him are called and chosen and faithful.”

Answer (score 1):

ESV Revelation 17:

> 12 And the ten horns that you saw are ten kings who have not yet received royal power, but they are to receive authority as kings for one hour, together with the beast. 13These are of one mind, and they hand over their power and authority to the beast. 14They will make **war** on the Lamb, and the Lamb will conquer them, for he is Lord of lords and King of kings, and those with him are called and chosen and faithful.”

These are faithful warriors, on top of being called and chosen.

Rev. 17:14b - In the context, are "those with him," called (by God, inviter) , and chosen and faithful (invitees), or called and chosen, and faithful?

I'd go with
"called and chosen, and faithful".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is in the verses themselves of Rev 17:

> **11** The beast that was, and now is not, is an eighth king, who belongs to the other seven and is going into destruction. **12** The
> ten horns you saw are ten kings who have not yet received a kingdom,
> but will receive one hour of authority as kings, along with the beast.
> **13** These kings have one purpose: to yield their power and authority to the beast.
>
> **14** They will make war against the Lamb, and the Lamb will triumph over them, because He is Lord of lords and King of kings; and He will
> be accompanied by His called and chosen and faithful ones.”

The passage makes a clear distinction between two groups:

- those who accompany the **beast**, the 10 kings and their accompanying armies
- those that accompany the **Lamb** who are "called and chosen and faithful ones".

This is similar to the distinction  made between the same two groups in other contexts such as:

- those who have the mark of the beast (Rev 13:16)
- those who have the seal of God and the Lamb (Rev 7:3, 4, 9, 14, 14:1, etc)

Comment: I rephrased the question to makes the point clearer, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, it quotes "and chosen and faithful" or "and chosen, and faithful". The question is not clear but I guess it means whether the people with Jesus;

1. are chosen by the Lord and faithful to the Lord
2. either chosen by the Lord, or faithful to the Lord

My argument is, can the chosen one unfaithful, and can the unfaithful one be chosen? So "1" is the only answer.